# D3js Stacked Barchart width is not propper

Tags: d3.js

i m trying to make a D3 bar chart, here bars are horizontal & it's width should be in percent. But i am having still some issue with its width. I have created a fiddle @ [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sumant86/m3g75qa0/2/). 
here you can see width is not proper, and same time its not align on y axis.

here its stacked with executed-placed-quantity. here executed is subset of placed, & placed is subset of quantity.

here barData m getting from Ajax call. in function getRanges i am preparing an array of bars, its returning me is

```
[[bar1 start point, bar1Length],[bar2 start point, bar2Length],[bar3 start point, bar3Length]];
```

This data only m iterating inside forEach to create bars.

Some How its going in wrong direction. may be my scale is not proper or dataset. The final Output i have to come up is as [image] .

Now i need some help on atleast on bar alignment. can anyone help me?

Comment: Tip: "is not proper" assumes that everyone agrees and knows what "proper" is. I suggest that you should describe what you wanted and what you expected, and then (even though you have a Fiddle) describe what you are seeing that is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating but not using your `d3.scale.linear()` scales to place your data.  Your `x` and `y` variables are functions which map your data to pixel positions.  For instance, your bar width is

```
 .attr("width", function (d, i) {
    return d[1] * 100; // what's the magic 100?
 })
```

This should be:

```
.attr("width", function(d, i) {
    return x(d[1]);
})
```

For placing values on the y axis you have:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.l + "," + (margin.t + (30 * j)) + ")")
```

Using the y scale it's

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.l + "," + (y(j) + margin.t - 25/2) + ")") // this will center the bar on the tick
```

Also, for you y axis you might want to switch to [ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) as you example looks like discreet categories and not a numeric range.

[Here's a few changes](http://plnkr.co/edit/cgxeuhq82ngejlVkLyyh?p=preview) that'll get you going.

Comment: Thanks Mark, your comments help me to understand what i was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to draw a stackedBar chart in horizontal

http://tributary.io/inlet/4966973